# What DC fan connector is this?

Tags: connector, identification, fan

I’m trying to identify the kind of connector I need for a few DC fans, but can’t track them down on digikey.  Pictures attached.  Pitch is 2.00mm, wire is 26AWG.  The replacement fans I possess have bare wires so I also need to attach the little metal clips (I guess?)

[image: image1]

[image: image2]

[image: image3]

Comment: Is the pitch really 2.00mm - ie have you measured accurately? If so the answer doesn't match your question because that's a 2.5mm pitch.

Comment: I put the terminal against a row of 2.54mm pitch headers I had next to me, and the terminal spacing was a touch smaller than the header pin spacing.  I will measure more accurately tonight and add a comment.

Answer (score 1):

It is a Japan Solderless Terminal / JST XH series, female 2 pin variation.

JST XHP-2 on Digikey http://www.digikey.com/product-detail/en/XHP-2/455-2266-ND/555485

The crimp terminals needed are linked on the Digikey page under related parts.